# Android - Imageview and setOnClickListener

Tags: android, imageview

Please explain me why the code does not work. Thanks for your help.

```
private boolean emotico = false;

ImageView emot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obrazek);
emot.setClickable(true);
emot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){
    ImageView emotico = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obrazek);
    if (emot) {
        emotico.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic2);
    } else {
        emotico.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic1);
    }
    emot = !emot;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want o image click

Comment: Extending the @justDroid comment I would also ask what mean with "does not work": Exception, wrong behavior (which one), etc.

Comment: you should research your issues more before coming for an easy answer :(

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol setClickable and setOnClickListener

Comment: Change `if (emot)` with `if (emotico)`

Comment: Also put `@Override` on `public void onClick(View v){`

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for you:

```
//emotico is a boolean variable
private boolean emotico = false;

//emot is a ImageView variable
ImageView emot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obrazek);
emot.setClickable(true);
emot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){
    //Two errors in your below line:
    //1. 'emotico' is a boolean and 'emot' being a ImageView variable can't be used together
    //2. You have already defined and instantiated it above, so no need to do it again
    //ImageView emotico = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obrazek);

    //we check for boolean conditions
    if (emotico) {
        //ImageView variable should be assigned here
        emot.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic2);
    } else {
        //ImageView variable should be assigned here
        emot.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic1);
    }
    //check for boolean condition here
    emotico = !emotico;
  }
}
```

Comment: @user5734658 check this out.

Comment: I have error Cannot resolve symbol setOnClickListener

Comment: @user5734658 please post your logcat so I can help you better

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the things and you are trying to map imageview again that view's onClickListener(), Please try this !

```
private boolean emotico = false;

ImageView emot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obrazek);
emot.setClickable(true);
emot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){

    if (emotico) {
        emot.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic2);
    } else {
        emot.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic1);
    }
    emotico = !emotico ;
}
}
```

Try this code ! Hope it will solve your problem ! :)

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol setClickable and setOnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

I believe you confused `emot(ImageView)` with `emotico(boolean flag)` in the `onClick()`

```
private boolean emotico = false;

final ImageView emot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obrazek);
emot.setClickable(true);
emot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v){
     emotico = !emotico;
     if (emotico) {
        emot.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic2);
     } else {
        emot.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic1);
     }
   }
}
```